# Отправка фото по file_id из базы данных , вместо фото отправляет file_id текстом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, aiogram

Есть бот. Задача следующая: админ через машину состояний вносит данные в БД, в том числе фото. С загрузкой и последующей отправкой, при условии одного фото проблем не было. Но фото должно быть несколько. Как сохранить альбомом, решения я не нашёл. В голову пришла следующая идея.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo','text'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def FSMAdmin_photo(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
  if message.from_user.id == ID:
    global List_photo
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        print(message)
        List_photo.append(message.photo[0].file_id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Загрузите следующее фото')
    elif message.content_type == 'text':
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo'] = ','.join(List_photo)
            print(data)
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите описание')
```

А вот при извлечении данных по запросу пользователя столкнулся с проблемой. Запись, в которой одно фото отправляется пользователю, но file_id приходит обычным текстом. Если фото было несколько, то вообще выдаёт ошибку:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-63' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, 
defined at C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Wrong remote file 
identifier specified: wrong string length')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\Handler\client.py", line 75, in command_read
await sqlite_db.sql_read(message)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\data_base\sqlite_db.py", line 23, in sql_read
await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, f'ОПИСАНИЕ:\n{i[1]}\nВНИМАНИЕ!!! Цена указана без 
учёта скидок\n{i[2]}')
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 
527, in send_photo
result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 
231, in request
return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, 
data, files,
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 
140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 
115, in check_result
exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\Desktop\Samani_Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", 
line 141, in detect
raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong remote file identifier specified: wrong string 
length
```

Вот сам хендлер и функция, которые выдают по запросу информацию из БД.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='Просмотреть')
async def command_read(message: types.Message):
await sqlite_db.sql_read(message)

async def sql_read(message):
for i in cur.execute('SELECT*FROM kitchen').fetchall():
    for photo in i:
        print(type(photo))
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, photo)
    await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, f'ОПИСАНИЕ:\n{i[1]}\nВНИМАНИЕ!!! Цена указана 
без учёта скидок\n{i[2]}')
```

Во входящем сообщении, при загрузке фото, тип данных у file_id "str", на выходе тип данных такой же.

Опыта очень мало и сломал уже голову. Хотелось бы понять где и что сделано неверно.
Буду рад конструктивной критике и советам.

Comment: Вы отправляете file_id как текст сообщение, используя методом `send_message`, какой результат вы ждете?

Comment: Так я его и сохраняю как текст. ID файла, с типом данных 'photo', на сервере телеграм этот файл храниться под этим id. И если в state, по ключу в словаре сохранять одно фото (data['photo']=message.photo[0].file_id), то при выгрузке из БД никаких проблем нет. Всё работает как положено. Вопросы начинаются после попыток записать в БД несколько ID. Возможно есть какие-то нюансы с изменением типов данных. Сначала в список, потом в строку, на выходе из БД это уже часть кортежа. Не знаю в чём именно проблема, и, именно это и хочу понять. В принципе могу дополнить вопрос кодом, который работал.

Comment: Если верить дословному переводу, то что-то не так с длинной строки: aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: указан неверный идентификатор удаленного файла: неправильная строка
длина. Возможно есть какой-то служебный символ.

Comment: Так-с, один косяк у себя нашёл. Мне во втором цикле for нужно вот так наверно сделать: for photo in i[0].split(','). У меня же там сейчас строка, с id-шниками через запятую. Нужно собрать в список, и потом уже итерировать.

Comment: @Рамис должен признать Вы оказались правы. send_photo действительно помогло. Хотя, пока для меня остаётся загадкой, почему в одном случае метод send_message так же был рабочим. Осталось только решить вопрос как вывести полученный результаты одним сообщением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Для себя нашёл следующее решение.

Хендлер, получающий информацию на входе, оставляем без изменений:

```
async def FSMAdmin_photo(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
if message.from_user.id == ID:
    global List_photo
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        List_photo.append(message.photo[0].file_id)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Загрузите следующее фото')
    elif message.content_type == 'text':
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo'] = ','.join(List_photo)
            await FSMAdmin.next()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите описание')
```

Важно, не забыть, перед выходом из машины состояний очистить список.

```
List_photo.clear()
await state.finish()
```

Ну и само решение:

```
async def sql_read(message):
for ret in cur.execute('SELECT*FROM kitchen').fetchall():
    group = types.MediaGroup()
    for photo in ret[0].split(','):
        group.attach_photo(photo)
    await bot.send_media_group(message.from_user.id, group)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,  f'ОПИСАНИЕ:\n{ret[1]}\nВНИМАНИЕ!!!
                           Цена указана без учёта скидок\n{ret[2]}')
```

Ответ нашёл вот здесь:
[Aiogram - отправка файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1411366/aiogram-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)