# Aiogram - отправка файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Есть код, хотелось бы чтобы бот отправлял файлы не отдельными сообщениями, а одним с прикрепленным текстом. Вот код для редактирования:

```
file1 = open(('http') + '.txt', 'rb')
await bot.send_document(chat_id, file1)
file2 = open(('socks4') + '.txt', 'rb')
await bot.send_document(chat_id, file2)
file3 = open(('socks5') + '.txt', 'rb')
await bot.send_document(chat_id, file3)
```

Если дополнительно объясните что да как, то цены вам не будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [sendDocument](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_document.html)

`caption: Optional[str]` - Заголовок к сообщению(`подпись`/прикреплённый текст), дает возможность отправить документ с текстовым сообщением.

```
await bot.send_document(chat_id = chat_id, document = file1, caption = "TEXT_MESSAGE")
```

### [sendMediaGroup](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_media_group.html)

> Используйте этот метод, чтобы отправить группу фотографий, видео,
> документов или аудио в виде альбома.

```
# Создать медиа группу
media = types.MediaGroup()

# Прикрепить/добавить файл, документ, аудио и тд.
media.attach_photo(types.InputFile('data/cat.jpg'), 'Cat!')
# Ещё файл - он так же может быть документом, аудио и тд.
media.attach_photo(types.InputFile('data/cats.jpg'), 'More cats!')

# Можно использовать URL ссылки на фото, документы и тд.
# Из документации - получить случайного кота:
media.attach_photo('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/', 'Random cat.')

# ID файла тоже подойдет для добавления в медиа группу.
# media.attach_photo('<file_id>', 'cat-cat-cat.')

# Готово! Можно отправлять!
await message.send_media_group(chat_id = chat_id, media=media)
#caption - использовать это свойство нужно при добавлении нового файла, т.е. - attach_photo(file, caption = "TEXT")
```

### [UPD:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893142/how-to-send-telegram-mediagroup-with-caption-text)

> Вы должны использовать `sendMediaGroup` , где вы можете указать
> `media` поле с массивом фото / видео объектов, но хитрость заключается в
> том, чтобы установить `caption` нужно сделать подпись только для первого элемента
> массива . В этом случае телеграмм покажет эту подпись под
> медиаконтентом.
>
> Если вы укажете подписи для более чем одного элемента, телеграмма
> покажет их только при нажатии на превью фото для каждого фото
> отдельно.

**[Пример использования MediaGroup](https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/media_group.html)**

Answer (score -1):

Добавь в `start_polling` `skip_updates` - чтобы пропускать те апдейты, которые были получены за время, когда бот был в офлайне - не обрабатывал в онлайн-режиме все апдейты. Т.к. бот в офлайне, скапливается куча апдейтов, которые нужно обработать.

Справка: `dp = Dispatcher(BOT_TOKEN)`

Таким образом, нужно написать:

```
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```